# Taking webcam photos via C# + EmguCV isn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, webcam, emgucv

Taking webcam photos via C# + EmguCV isn't work. EmguCV version 3.1.0.1 (because of Visual Studio 2015, .NET Framework 4.5.2). OS Windows 10. My code (too much dispose() to be sure):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using ZXing;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Capture capture;
        Bitmap image;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (capture != null)
                {
                    capture.QueryFrame().Dispose();
                    capture.Dispose();
                }

                if (image != null)
                {
                    image.Dispose();
                }

                capture = new Capture();
                image = capture.QueryFrame().Bitmap;
                image.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\img.jpg");
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (capture != null)
                {
                    capture.QueryFrame().Dispose();
                    capture.Dispose();
                }

                if (image != null)
                {
                    image.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's strange that this code works only one time and I get a photo. However, the app freezes on all subsequent attempts without any exception message. After restarting the computer, the application works correctly again only one time. With this behavior, it seems that some OS resource is not released after code execution.

Comment: I can suggest you to try use AForge.NET

Comment: The order of the `Dispose()` calls as well as the call to `capture.QueryFrame().Dispose()` seems fishy to me. `QueryFrame()` may return `null`, and the `image` instance may hold references to `capture`, which you dispose first. Could you try disposing instances in the reverse order (the last one created is first one disposed). Also, does instantiating the `Capture` instance only once (e.g. in the constructor) make a difference?

Comment: I have spent some time interfacing with web cameras and reached the conclusion that not all libraries and APIs are 100% stable. You might use the library incorrectly, but it might also be bugs in the library. In the end it might be worth it to try something else.

Answer (score 1):

I modified my code with @sunside recommendations, and it works! Before asking on stackoverflow I tried many modifications, including without dispose, but they didn't work.
I don't know where was a mistake. The working code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using ZXing;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Capture capture;
        Mat mat;
        Bitmap image;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            capture = new Capture();
            this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (image != null) image.Dispose();
                if (mat != null) mat.Dispose();

                mat = capture.QueryFrame();
                image = mat.Bitmap;
                image.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\img.jpg");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (image != null) image.Dispose();
                if (mat != null) mat.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if(capture != null) capture.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```